# Time out set function on javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a `setTimeout` function for some music to play for 30 seconds, can someone please help me to add it to my code

```
function playSound(el,soundfile) {
  if (el.mp3) {
    if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
    else el.mp3.pause();
  } else {
    el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
    el.mp3.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is mysql and php tags doing in this question?

Comment: Why don't you just add it? If something isn't working, we may help you but, asking for code never works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` takes two params. First is callback function and another is time in milliseconds. Use `setTimeout` as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playSound(el, soundfile) {
        if (el.mp3) {
            if (el.mp3.paused)
                el.mp3.play();
            else
                el.mp3.pause();
        } else {
            el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
            el.mp3.play();
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.mp3.pause();
        }, 30000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: [I guess it does...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043065/can-someone-add-set-time-out-function-on-this-javascript-code#comment89077073_51043065) It is advisable not to answer questions like this that show no effort.

Comment: What if person, who asked question, doesn't have idea where to write the code.

Comment: i tried to add that's why i asked for help, now its working

Comment: @silvabizhub you never showed your attempt.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh then they should learn by finding examples on the internet, there are many, many, many, examples of `setTimeout`, what they are asking is extremely basic.

Comment: I agree. But there should be an answer to question asked here.

Comment: You have to ask yourself if their question meets this spec https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Generally, I will use the comments below the question to try and get them edit their question so it is more in line with the guidelines.

Comment: This is a useful place to get stock comments from https://sopython.com/wiki/Useful_Comments 

Comment: I understand guys thanks i'll do more on the next time won't happen again